# Odd behaviour if querystring begins with an ampersand

Tags: iis, asp-classic, query-string, request.querystring

I've isolated an odd behavior in ASP Classic, Windows server 2016, IIS 10.0

Run this code:

```
For Each Item in Request.QueryString
    Response.Write Item & ": " & Request.QueryString(Item) & "<br/>"
Next
```

with this querystring:

```
?&var1=value1&var2=value2
```

I'm getting this output:

```
&var1: value1 
var2: value2
```

So basically ASP Classic is screwing first variable, which should be `var1`. Because of the first ampersand in the URL, the first variable is not recognized correctly.

Is there a way to configure IIS to enable correct parsing of the URL ? If I take away the first ampersand, `var1` is recognized correctly.

Comment: It doesn't look like the url format is correct. first character of the query should be the name of the first variable https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4

Comment: I've had this before a long time ago and worked around it by adding a stub-variable as the first variable. However, I haven't needed that trick in ages... Not sure what causes this. EDIT: Alex M is right; first variable doesn't need an ampersand.

Comment: This isn’t *“odd behaviour”*, it’s behaving as it should do. The URL is malformed *(if you don’t expect it to make up part if the first key name)* so the first ampersand is interpreted as part of the key name *(a HTTP GET querystring is just a bunch of key value pairs)*.

Comment: @AlexM thanks! Alas, the `query` rule in the ABNF suggest that it could be formed by zero or more `pchar`, and a `pchar` could be a `sub-delims` and `&` is a `sub-delims`, so a querystring like `&&` alone is correct ? Guess I'll follow @ErikOosterwaal workaround.

Comment: @Niloct no it doesn’t. It does when referring to the path component not the query, try reading URI scheme document again.

Comment: @Niloct there is no need to include the tech in the question title, that is what tags are for, so not "irrelevant" at all.

Comment: If you really can't touch to your QueryString parameters, a simple workaround is to loop through the Request.Querystring colleciton, then to replace the & in every item that have one.