# ? vs ?& in url for the first parameter in axios

Tags: url, parameters

I understand that ? marks the start of url query string and & the start of the subsequent parameter, like so:

```
?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

This is an alternative that i am being told would also work, but is this good practice?

```
?&key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Comment: It's legal per the relevant RFC, but I would be very cautious about using it - whatever's receiving the request may not interpret a [leading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48325204/3001761) (or [trailing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6663362/3001761)) ampersand how you expect. Axios will handle this for you if you set `params: { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }` in the options object anyway, you don't need to bake it into the URL yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Axios seems to handle it with the params option just like you say.